# Where find open code-source Spark-streaming Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm looking for the open code-source of Spark-streaming-kafka with scala
Please do you have an idea about it's link on Apache where can I found it ?
Thanks

Comment: Spark Streaming Kafka is deprecated. You want `spark-sql-kafka-0-10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of what you're looking for but one of those two links should help:

- Spark source code is available on GitHub: https://github.com/apache/spark
- `spark-streaming-kafka` source code can be downloaded via Maven dependency in your IDE for instance (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.11/1.6.3/spark-streaming-kafka_2.11-1.6.3-sources.jar)